# Terminology: output of a regression model as input to another regression model

Tags: multiple-regression, terminology

I have a question about terminology. I've constructed a multiple linear regression model for a variable **X**. This model is in turn used to estimate values of **X** that are used as input when constructing another multiple linear regression for a variable **Y**. Is there a term for this sort of approach?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a bit like Two Stage Least Squares from [instrumental variable econometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variable#Applications). This is done when you have simultaneity, measurement error in X, or an omitted variable that is correlated with X in your Y regression. However, there are some stringent conditions that X has to to satisfy for the approach to be appropriate.